# Mix objects with objects and arrays to store individual settings and retrieve them

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to store several **general extension settings and specific website settings**.

I need to save a website name if it's not yet saved and according to its number retrieve the individual settings.

Would the below setup be the best approach using an object with object for websites number & name (key/value) while for website settings array with objects that use the number of the arrays of the website?

And how can I do a check if a website is saved and then return its settings?
Do i need to use indexof or findIndex?

```
const extensionsettings = {
   websites: {
      1: 'website 1',
      2: 'website 2',
      3: 'website 3'
        },
   websitesettings: [
     {
    1: {
      color: 'green',
      size: '12'
        },
    }, 
    {
    2: {
      color: 'red',
      size: '10'
        }
    }, 
    {
    3: {
      color: 'blue',
      size: '20'
        }
    }
  ],
    general: {
      optionalsetting1: 'yes',
      optionalsetting2: 'no'
        },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one 'best' approach but you can consider what the domain you are working in consists of, and then try to get your data structure to reflect that domain. This will make some operations much easier.

For example, you will only have a `websiteSettings` field for a given website if that site itself is already stored. As a result, you can keep the settings in the same object as the site address.

```js
let extensionsettings = {
   websites: {
      'website 1': {
          color: 'green',
          size: '12'
      },
      'website 2': {
          color: 'red',
          size: '10'
      },
      'website 3': {
          color: 'blue',
          size: '20'
      }
   },
    general: {
      optionalsetting1: 'yes',
      optionalsetting2: 'no'
    },
};

// function to check whether site already has settings
const siteHasSettings = (settings, siteName) => {
    return settings.websites[siteName] !== undefined;
}

const updateSettings = (settings, siteName, newSetting) => {
    // initialise settings object if site doesn't have settings yet
    if (!siteHasSettings(settings, siteName)) {
        settings.websites[siteName] = {};
    }
    settings.websites[siteName] = {...settings.websites[siteName], ...newSetting};
    return settings;
}

// sample code for working with data
const siteName = 'stackoverflow.com'

console.log(`No settings yet for '${siteName}': ${extensionsettings.websites[siteName]}`);

extensionsettings = updateSettings(extensionsettings, siteName, {color: 'yellow', size: 15});

console.log(`Settings for '${siteName}': ${JSON.stringify(extensionsettings.websites[siteName])}`);

extensionsettings = updateSettings(extensionsettings, siteName, {color: 'orange', backgroundcolor: 'purple'});

console.log(`Updated settings for '${siteName}': ${JSON.stringify(extensionsettings.websites[siteName])}`);
```

Expected output:

> No settings yet for 'stackoverflow.com': undefined
> Settings for 'stackoverflow.com': {"color":"yellow","size":15}
> Updated settings for 'stackoverflow.com': {"color":"orange","size":15,"backgroundcolor":"purple"}

This lets you update the settings object with new values overwriting old ones, but old values getting kept if there is no new value for that key.

---

To set `chrome.storage.sync.set` and `chrome.storage.sync.get` you would need to create objects which hold those values, and then pass them to the `updateSettings()` method above:

```js
const newSettingValue = { chrome: { storage: { sync: { set: true } } } }
extensionsettings = updateSettings(extensionsettings, siteName, newSettingValue)
```

Comment: Good point. Using each website's name as the key for its own settings is better if OP doesn't actually need to be able to use arbitrary numeric keys because your data structure is simpler to work with.

Comment: Wow thanks, excellent point, especially as I'm thinking forward about exporting these and importing into another browser where potentially they would have different numbers assigned to each website but not with your approach, brilliant! I didn't realise that I could use them as key, I thought they don't support spaces or special characters. =) I still get an error though `Uncaught ReferenceError: siteName is not defined` https://jsfiddle.net/markusd1984/80we7cn9/

Comment: I need to first check if website exists, if not add to the object of websites.
If it exists, use the settings, which I understand will be saved in `siteHasSettings` so i can show them in fields within extension popup, right?

Comment: `siteHasSettings()` is a function which lets you quickly check whether an existing site already has settings. The data is stored in `extensionsettings` still. You can look up the values for a site by going to `extensionsettings.websites['google.com']` for example, and you can set new values as follows: `extensionsettings.websites['new site name.com'] = newSettingsObject`

Comment: Thanks @Dakeyras you rock. Could you also show me how to add `chrome.storage.sync.set` & `chrome.storage.sync.get` in this scenario please?

Comment: @Markus done, check the new bit at the bottom :)

Comment: Oh wow gotta try that later on, amazing about the many possibilities and ways to code, learning lots, much appreciated, have a nice day @Dakeyras

Answer (score 1):

If you want to supply your own numeric keys as your current code does, then the array is an unnecessary extra layer.
You could omit it and do something like this to get website information, if it exists:

```js
// Demonstates info retrieval
const settingsGlobal = getExtensionSettings();
logSiteInfo('website 3');
logSiteInfo('website 42');

function logSiteInfo(website){
  const siteInfo = getSiteInfo(website, settingsGlobal);
  console.log(`${website}:`);
  console.log(siteInfo ?? " ...not found");
}

// For each stored website: if value matches needle, uses key to get settings
function getSiteInfo(needle, haystack){
  const entries = Object.entries(haystack.websites); // entries are len-2 arrays
  for(const [key, value] of entries){ // Destructures each entry
    if(value === needle){
      return haystack.websiteSettings[key];
    }
  }
  return null; // Desired website value was not found
}

// Provides storage object
function getExtensionSettings(){
  const extensionSettings = {
     websites: { 1: 'website 1', 2: 'website 2', 3: 'website 3' },
     websiteSettings: {
        1: { color: 'green', size: '12' },
        2: { color: 'red', size: '10' },
        3: { color: 'blue', size: '20' }
      },
      general: { optionalsetting1: 'yes', optionalsetting2: 'no' }
  };
  return extensionSettings;
}
```